# Is there Redis client for v8? (Not NodeJs)

Tags: redis, v8

I have a NodeJs server connecting to redis. I also have a program using v8 engine. I was wondering if there is any redis client library for v8 too.

It would be awesome if there is one. Also could we use existing C client hiredis without any modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redis-node-client](https://github.com/nikhilm/redis-node-client) looks like it supports Google V8 as well as node.js

Comment: This gave an example how redis functions can be wrapped up with v8 handles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

it also have hiredis binding if hiredis is available on your system